# OptionMenu add_command needs direct command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, optionmenu, tkinter.optionmenu

I am stuck

I am changing the content of an OptionMenu with the refresh() function and it works fine in case A but when in case B where I change it to a callback the OptionMenu stops working. Clicking on an option no longer selects it.

Any idea what makes it so?

Case A:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
cvar = tk.StringVar(root)
cvar.set("-")
optionlist = ('one', 'two', 'three')

def refresh(contentlist):
    optionmenu['menu'].delete(0, 'end')

    for content in contentlist:
        optionmenu['menu'].add_command(label=content, command=tk._setit(cvar, content))

def doNothing():
    return

optionmenu = tk.OptionMenu(root, cvar, *optionlist, command=doNothing)
optionmenu.pack()

refresh(optionlist)

root.mainloop()
```

Case B:

```
def contentcallback(var, name):
    tk._setit(var, name)

def refresh(contentlist):
    optionmenu['menu'].delete(0, 'end')

    for content in contentlist:
        optionmenu['menu'].add_command(label=content, command=contentcallback(cvar, content))
```

Comment: @stovfl I hope this is to your satisfaction

Comment: Should be read `command=tk._setit(cvar, content, doNothing))` and `def doNothing(event):`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5767228/7432

Answer (score 0):

@stovfl made a comment that gave me another solution

tk._setit has a callback function I did not know about. Using that callback I can do:

```
def contentcallback(var, name):
    #Whatever I need to do

def refresh(contentlist):
    optionmenu['menu'].delete(0, 'end')

    for content in contentlist:
        optionmenu['menu'].add_command(label=content, command=tk._setit(var, name, lambda cv=cvar, con=content: contentcallback(cv, con)))
```

EDIT:
@BryanOakley gave a link to why my original solution was full of holes

The tk._setit method returns an object that is needed to make it work. The original contentcallback only called the method and not the one behind it. This made it a little weird to setup:

```
def contentcallback(var, name, func):
    #Whatever I need to do
    func()

def refresh(contentlist):
    optionmenu['menu'].delete(0, 'end')

    for content in contentlist:
        optionmenu['menu'].add_command(label=content, command=lambda cv=cvar, co=content, func=tk._setit(cvar, content): contentcallback(cvar, co, func))
```

Comment: `cvar.get()` inside `def callback(...` does the same without `lambda ...`